# Why does 100% height = 0px in this context?

Tags: html, css

Given the following HTML:

```
<div class='page-header'>
    <h1>Header</h1>
    <div class="thingy">
    </div>
</div>
```

And the following CSS:

```
.page-header {
    background-color: blue;
    border: 5px solid green;
}

h1 {
    background-color: red;
    display: inline-block;
}

.thingy {
    float: right;
    height: 100%;
    width: 20px;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Why is the `div` with `class='thingy'` not visible?

[image: Rendering of the above HTML. Yellow box is not visible.]

[View in JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ajedi32/r9Zx6/)

Changing to the height to a fixed value makes it visible, but that's not what I want. I want the element's height to scale with the height of the element it's in. How do I do that?

Comment: because it has no content

Comment: Unfortunately for height, the parent must have a defined height in order to use a percentage.

Comment: Why should it? You've specified a height of 100% but it's 100% of nothing since the parent has no height declared. If you declare a height, it works http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/r9Zx6/1/

Comment: @StephenThomas But if you change `height: 100%;` to `height: 50px;` it works, even though it still has no content.

Comment: 100% of unknown can't be calculated. 50px can.

Comment: @j08691 Just because I haven't defined a height, that doesn't mean the element has no height. In my example, Chrome's dev tools inform me that the element has a height of 89px.

Comment: @BrianS But why is it unknown? As I said in my previous comment, Chrome knows what height the element has. (89px)

Comment: I understand where you're coming from; it does make some sense for 100% height to automatically fill the parent, regardless of other issues, but that's simply not how CSS height works.

Comment: @BrianS Bah, well okay then. I guess I'll have to figure out some other way of doing this...

Comment: You can probably get the results you want by modifying the elements' styles via JavaScript/jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As as stated in my comment, it's because none of that element's parents have a declared height. Why does that matter? Becuase that's just how it works.

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/height):

> The percentage is calculated with respect to the height of the
>   generated box's containing block. **If the height of the containing
>   block is not specified explicitly (i.e., it depends on content
>   height), and this element is not absolutely positioned, the value
>   computes to auto**. A percentage height on the root element is relative
>   to the initial containing block.

Comment: Ah! There's the key! "and this element is not absolutely positioned". Fixed: http://jsfiddle.net/Ajedi32/TJvrr/ I guess I just needed to RTFM.

Comment: Yup, if you're willing to change the positioning then that will work without having to specify a height on an ancestor.

Answer (score 3):

Because you didn't give the height to the parent element

try with this

```
.page-header {
    background-color: blue;
    border: 5px solid green;
    height:60px;
}
```

[Js Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/r9Zx6/3/)

Comment: But what if I don't want the parent to have a fixed height?

Comment: @Ajedi32, then you would need to add content to the empty div.

Answer (score 2):

This is bacause the parent container doesn't have set any height.
If you set any fixed height ( in px for example) for `.page-header`, then `.thingy` will also have this height.

For example:

```
.page-header {
    background-color: blue;
    border: 5px solid green;
    height: 100px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/r9Zx6/2/

**Edit:**

If you want it to automatically adjust and always fit 100% of parent height you can try a "hack" like this:

First you set huge vertical padding and the same but negative margin:

```
.thingy {
    float: right;
    height: 100%;
    width: 20px;
    background-color: yellow;
    padding: 1000px 0;
    margin: -1000px 0;
}
```

then set `overflow:hidden` to parent:

```
.page-header {
    background-color: blue;
    border: 5px solid green;    
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/r9Zx6/5/

Should work in this case but it also depends on what you're trying to achieve in the end.

Another way is to use javascript but I don't think it's a good idea to involve JS to such cosmetic issues.

Comment: Okay, I'm glad to see that at least that works. What I don't get though is why the parent element has to have a fixed height for my example to work. What if I don't want the parent to have a fixed height? What if I'd rather have the height be dynamic based on the element's other contents?

Comment: I agree that setting the height fixed like this: `.page-header {
    background-color: blue;
    border: 5px solid green;
    height: 100px;
}` gets the job done. See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/harveyramer/D4FNd/

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the reactions I will get for this but as a possible solution.

if you set the page-header to

```
position:relative
```

and then set the thingy class to

```
position:absolute;
right:0px;
top:0px;
```

you no longer need the float:right and it has the same height as the parent.

[here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r9Zx6/6/)

Comment: Yup, this is probably the solution I'll end up using.

Answer (score 0):

`height: 100%;` means what is the exact height of the child not the parent, so using it in that context is pointless since the height is automatically 100% and sadly there is no height so the container isn't shown.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another alternative, although it requires jQuery:

`$(function() {
    $('.thingy').height($('.thingy').parent().height());
});`

Comment: I really dislike the idea of using JavaScript for styling, but I guess that does work...

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be what you are trying to achieve. The "header" element grows to accommodate the elements it contains (I put a min-height on "thingy" just to show where it is when viewed in browser).

```
<html>
  <head>
  <style>
    .header {background-color: blue; border: 5px solid green; height: auto; overflow: hidden;}
    .thingy {float: right; height: auto; min-height: 100px; width: 20px; background-color: yellow;}
    h1 {background-color: red; display: inline-block;}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div class="header">
        <h1>
      header
      </h1>
    <div class="thingy"></div>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't work. The idea is that `thingy` must fill 100% of the header's height, regardless of how tall the header becomes. Your example only works up until the header exceeds 100px in height.